# CSipSimple libvpx patching file error

Tags: android, csip-simple

I'm trying to compile CSipSimple according to `https://sourceforge.net/p/csipsimple/wiki/HowToBuild/` and got this error

```
fatal: repository 'https://code.google.com/p/webm.libvpx/' not found
```

So, I manually download the source code from `https://chromium.googlesource.com/webm/libvpx` and change the folder name into "sources" under folder ../jni/libvpx
I build it again and got
[this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cWykw.png)

Is this the right approach to download libvpx there?
What should I do to solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to create source folder in jni
Go to jni/libvpx/Makefile 
Open Makefile , find sources ,  and change 
@ git clone https://code.google.com/p/webm.libvpx sources; \
to
@ git clone https://chromium.googlesource.com/webm/libvpx sources; \